# Compile time optimization of Math.pow

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I've read that it's possible to optimize multiplication by a known constant at compile time by generating code which makes clever use of bit shifting and compiler-generated magic constants.

I'm interested in possibilities for optimizing exponentiation in a similar hacky manner. I know about [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), so I guess you could aggressively optimize

```
pow(CONSTANT, n)
```

by embedding precomputed successive squares of CONSTANT into the executable. I'm not sure whether this is actually a good idea.

But when it comes to

```
pow(n, CONSTANT)
```

I can't think of anything. Is there a known way to do this efficiently? Do the minds of StackOverflow have ideas, on either problem?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you trying to implement `pow()` yourself, or are you assuming that the implementors of this function on your platform did a bad job and didn't try to optimize the easy cases?

Comment: I think the point is that compilers can take advantage of information that's not available to the function.  For example, `pow(x, 2)` can be implemented as `x * x`, but only at the expense of a run-time check that the second argument is 2; a compiler can replace the function call by an in-line multiplication no overhead for the test.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sir , i came on this question looking for compiler time optimization. But I do not understand how does compiler do optimization when `pow(10,2)` is there.

Comment: @KeithThompson And Why`pow(a,b)` is implemented as `exp(b * log(a))` ? And not as a loop.

Comment: @SurajJain: If you have a question, post a question.

Comment: @SurajJain: Apparently users can sometimes be limited to one question per week. If you're in that position, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited). You might also take a look at [meta] for questions with the "post-ban" tag, particularly [this FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/827263). Bypassing the Q&A mechanism by asking questions in comments, directed to individual users, is not the way to fix it.

Comment: @SurajJain: Can you post a question on [meta]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `pow(a,b)` is implemented as `exp(b * log(a))` (which it probably is), if `a` is a constant then you can precompute its `log`. If `b` is a constant, it only helps if it is also an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiation by squaring is ideal for the second case, just basically unroll the loop and embed the constants. But only if CONSTANT is an integer of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could use addition chain exponentiation, this is a smart way to reduce the number of CPU cycles for known integer exponents : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation